# Removing Green Background and Replace it with other

Tags: python, opencv

So i'm having a problem with removing green background and replacing it, . I have this black box in a green background. When i replaced it with np.where(pixel == 0), the program chooses the black box and the mask to replace with another background. How do i fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame = cv2.imread("black_box.jpg")
back_ground= cv2.imread("back_ground.jpg")


if back_ground.shape != frame.shape:
    back_ground = cv2.resize(back_ground,(frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0]))
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_green = np.array([42, 180, 39])
green = np.array([81,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_green,green)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

fg = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask = mask_inv)

fg = np.where(fg == 0,back_ground,fg)

cv2.imshow("fg",fg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Which one is it? *"everything is fine but i want to improve its performance a little bit"* or *"the program chooses the black box and the mask to replace with another background. How do i fix this problem"*?

Comment: the program chooses the black box and the mask to replace with another background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are some confusion on what your image is and what your background is. You apply the hsv conversion to the black and green image to detect the green then you do a bitwise_and mask with that mask and the same input image.
My code below gives, I believe, what you are after.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

frame = cv2.imread("im2.png")
back_ground= cv2.imread("im1.png")


if back_ground.shape != frame.shape:
    back_ground = cv2.resize(back_ground,(frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0]))
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(back_ground,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_green = np.array([42, 180, 39])
green = np.array([81,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_green,green)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

fg = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask = mask)
fg_inv = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask = mask_inv)

#fg = np.where(fg == 0,back_ground,fg) - unnecessary

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("fg", fg)
cv2.imshow("mask_inv", mask_inv)
cv2.imshow("fg_inv", fg_inv)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, when i tried to run your code with different image. Example: A bullet with green screen, The bullet became black. So i don't think this is the soluton i'm looking for

Comment: The bullet became black, even in the invert masked image ?